What is the meaning of open and closed circles in the predicted/expected graph output of ecospat.boyce?
I am running ecospat.boyce from the ecospat package in RStudio to try and evaluate a habitat suitability model. I am getting an output graph with both opened and closed circles. Unfortunately, I can't find out what the different circles mean.
When I looked it up, I couldn't find anything relevant about the given function, though for ecospat.mantel.correlogram the open circles apparently mean spatial autocorrelation isn't significantly different from zero. If that's the case for ecospat.boyce, though, I'm not sure why that's significant information.
The code used was:
BoyceFish <- ecospat.boyce (fit = DistributionData$Fish , obsFish, nclass=0, 
               window.w="default", res=100, PEplot = TRUE)
BoyceFish

The resulting image is attached


"Black circles indicate that the values are significative different from zero. White circles indicate non significant autocorrelation."

Looking at the code for ecospat.boyce here, the plot is created with
r<-1:length(f)
if(rm.duplicate == TRUE){
  r <- c(1:length(f))[f != c( f[-1],TRUE)]  #index to remove successive duplicates
}

<code omitted>

plot(HS, f, xlab = "Habitat suitability", ylab = "Predicted/Expected ratio", col = "grey", cex = 0.75)
points(HS[r], f[r], pch = 19, cex = 0.75)

pch = 19 is a closed circle and the default value appears to be 1, corresponding to an open circle.  [Here.]
So I believe that first all points are plotted with open circles and then those indexed r, corresponding to "not successive duplicates" are overwritten by closed circles.
One way to test my theory is to recreate your plot with rm.duplicate = FALSE: all points should be filled circles.
[I have never used the ecospat package.]
